# Manga where the main character is reborn, joins the army, and carries his squad

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I think it was the Korean army as he entered the army after school after being reborn. in the beginning his squad don't like him cause they think his out performing them to be spiteful but one realizes that he's just not good socially so they end up liking him and using him to help win a competition (best squad).

I believe the first parts of the story are where he is still in school)

Comment: What are the science fiction or fantasy elements in this manga? If there aren't any, this is not the forum to ask.

Comment: he got reborn though im not sure if that would make it fantasy do u happen to know what forum i could post this on

Comment: Reborn would qualify as fantasy. Can you add in more details related to this? For example, how did he die? What was his life like before dying, especially compared to his second life? Did he excel in the army because he had already gone through his service, and then went back in time to when he should be a trainee? Stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is [The Decent of the Demon Master](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/descent-of-the-demon-master)

The description does not say anything about him joining the military, because he only joins it in chapter 37, and only because he has to do his military service. As you describe, the squad does not like him at first, but they come to like him later (and at least one of them stays with him after they finish their service).

Comment: your my hero thks